# Controlling for a variable highly correlated with the variable of interest

Tags: causality, confounding

I want to see if there's a relationship between $x$ and $y$. A variable $z$ is highly (but not perfectly) correlated with $x$. I want to check that $z$ is only related $y$ through $x$, and not directly. Which of these two approaches should I use?

(1) I can check that if I limit the data set to keep $z$ is in a relatively small range, the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is still present. Of course, when $z$ is in a small range, $x$ doesn't change as much as it does without this restriction; this makes it harder to detect the relationship between $x$ and $y$. I suppose I can also repeat this for multiple such ranges of $z$.

(2) I can check that when I keep $x$ in a small range, the relationship between $z$ and $y$ disappears. Again, since $x$ is in a small range, the values of $z$ also don't change too much.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend a structural equation modeling approach, where you compare the fits of several structural models that are in line with your proposed theories. For example, if you think x is the causal variable and z has no effect, specify a model with a null effect from z to y. Then do the same reversing z and x. Whichever model has superior fit might be indicative of the model conforming best with the true causal model.